# PowerShell/XML toast notification for rebooting computer not working. Is there a specific XML command I can use?

Tags: xml, powershell

I am working on a reboot reminder toast notification and am very confused why the functionality for my "Reboot Now" button isn't doing anything. I used a PS script to create and display the notification but am unsure how to give the button proper functionality. Does it need to be in the XML or PS script and how would I make sure that it runs only when the button is pressed?

```
[xml]$ToastTemplate = @"
    <toast>
        <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <image placement="hero" src="$HeroImage"/>
            <image id="1" placement="appLogoOverride" hint-crop="circle" src="$LogoImage"/>
            <text placement="attribution">$AttributionText</text>
            <text>$HeaderText</text>
            <group>
                <subgroup>
                    <text hint-style="title" hint-wrap="true" >$TitleText</text>
                </subgroup>
            </group>
            <group>
                <subgroup>
                    <text hint-style="body" hint-wrap="true" >$BodyText1</text>
                </subgroup>
            </group>
            <group>
                <subgroup>
                    <text hint-style="body" hint-wrap="true" >$BodyText2</text>
                </subgroup>
            </group>
        </binding>
        </visual>
        <actions>
            <action arguments = "restart" content = 'Reboot Now' activationtype = "protocol" />
            <action activationType="system" arguments="dismiss" content="$DismissButtonContent"/>
        </actions>
    </toast>
"@

    #Load the ToastTemplate into the required format
    $ToastXml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
    $ToastXml.LoadXml($ToastTemplate.OuterXml)

    #Display the toast notification
    $AppID = '{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
    $Notification = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($AppID)
    $Notification.Show($ToastXml)
```

[Picture of Toast Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKB60.png)

Comment: The Dismiss button has the $DismissButtonContent variable but that literally does nothing. I had an $ActionButtonContent variable in which I used the restert-computer PS CMDLET but, that just rebooted the computer when the toast was displayed not when I clicked the button.

Comment: Why not use the the BurntToast module? [Find-Module -Name '*toast*' | Format-Table -AutoSize]. See the video on the module --- [Module Monday: BurntToast - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwZjr66yfc8) or it's [help file](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: I would use the BurntToast Module if this worked
New-BTButton -Content "Restart Now" -Arguments Restart-Computer
alas nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML/WPF/UWP/WinForm notwithstanding. [You have no form actions/events coded in your UI at all.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts) Hence the reason for actions is happening. Regardless of language, UX/UI design is the same and [you must assign code to the UI to do anything via events](https://www.bing.com/search?q=wpf%20form%20events&form=ANNTH1&refig=3586e58907154931a42796123e4e8423&sp=-1&pq=wpf%20form%20events&sc=1-15&qs=n&sk=&cvid=3586e58907154931a42796123e4e8423).

Here is an example answer I provided to another OPs' code regarding a similar question. This creates a tray app and right-clicking that pops the UI menu options to act on. Left-clicking executes the code-behind function actions. It is those types of events you are missing in your code.

```
#region Begin code behind logic
#
function Test-Administrator 
{
    ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::
    GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator") 
}

function Get-Sysx {
    $System  = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
    $Mem     = [math]::Ceiling($System.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
    $wmi     = gwmi -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer "."
    $LBTime  = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.Lastbootuptime)

    [TimeSpan]$uptime = New-TimeSpan $LBTime $(get-date)

    $s = "" 
    
    if ($uptime.Days -ne 1) {$s = "s"}

    $uptime_string = "$($uptime.days) day$s $($uptime.hours) hr $($uptime.minutes) min $($uptime.seconds) sec"
    "$Mem GB"
    "Up: $uptime_string"
}
#
#endregion End code behind logic

#region Begin GUI logic
#
# Load Assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$MyIcon = [Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Get-Command powershell).Path)

# Create Primary form
$objForm               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Visible       = $false
$objForm.WindowState   = "minimized"
$objForm.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$objForm.add_Closing({ $objForm.ShowInTaskBar = $False })

$objNotifyIcon         = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.Icon    = $MyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.Text    = "TrayUtility"
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $true

$objContextMenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu

$ToggleMenuItemPS       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ToggleMenuItemPS.Index = 1
$ToggleMenuItemPS.Text  = "New PowerShell"

if (Test-Administrator) { $ToggleMenuItemPS.Text = "New PowerShell (Admin)" }

$ToggleMenuItemPS.add_Click({
    Start-Process PowerShell.exe
})

$ToggleMenuItemFunction       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.Index = 2
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.Text  = "Mem and Uptime"
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.add_Click({
    
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($(Get-Sysx), 'Information', 0)
})

# Create an Exit Menu Item
$ExitMenuItem       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ExitMenuItem.Index = 5
$ExitMenuItem.Text  = "E&xit"
$ExitMenuItem.add_Click({
    $objForm.Close()
    $objNotifyIcon.visible = $false
})

# Add the Menu Items to the Context Menu
[void]$objContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($ToggleMenuItemPS)
[void]$objContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($ToggleMenuItemFunction)
[void]$objContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($ExitMenuItem)

# Assign the Context Menu
$objNotifyIcon.ContextMenu = $objContextMenu
$objForm.ContextMenu = $objContextMenu
#endregaion End GUI logic


# Show the Form - Keep it open
[void]$objForm.ShowDialog()
$objForm.Dispose()
```

Many examples exists all over the web...

Another code sample.

> https://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=18877

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
 
# Remove and Unregister events if created earlier. Tip, remove the events you haven’t created earlier
#Remove-Event BalloonClicked_event -ea SilentlyContinue
#Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier BalloonClicked_event -ea silentlycontinue
#Remove-Event BalloonClosed_event -ea SilentlyContinue
#Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier BalloonClosed_event -ea silentlycontinue
 
Remove-Event Clicked_event -ea SilentlyContinue
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier Clicked_event -ea silentlycontinue
    
# Create the object and customize the message
$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = 'Info'
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = 'Technology Notification'
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = 'Google Plugin was installed! ' + [DateTime]::Now.ToShortTimeString()
$objNotifyIcon.Text = 'Technology Notification'
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True
 
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $objNotifyIcon -EventName Click -SourceIdentifier Clicked_event -Action {
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Hello')
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $False
#[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Clicked','Information');$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $False
} | Out-Null   
 
# Show Notification
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000)
```

... [and on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20wpf%20toast%20button).

Comment: How does this relate to the Toast-Scenario? I have the exact same issue as in the question - I need a Toast-Message (not a balloon-tip nor a windows-form) with yes/no-buttons and I need to continue the script, if the user pressed "yes".

Comment: Are you talking about use cases like what is shown in [these images](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=Windows+toast+notification+%27yes+no+button%27&form=HDRSC2&first=1&scenario=ImageBasicHover)? If so that is what the BurntToast module provides.